# How does reputation on meta work?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Do [the same rules as SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130654/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/130656#130656) apply?

(really missing the ability to edit other people's posts right now - gotten used to correcting all spelling errors, etc. and now I can't)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to earn it here.

There are some discussions about reputation transfer between the sites, but the prevailing view seems to be that because the areas of discussion are different the rep should be kept separate.